# How to get device information in Linux

Tags: c, linux, linux-device-driver

I am beginner to linux, How to get devices information about keyboard, mouse etc connected to my linux machine (using C/java prg)

Comment: this may give you some direction http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193625/howto-get-hardware-information-in-linux-using-c

Comment: this is for harddisk... i want to know about usb devices like mouse,keyboard etc..anyway thanx @bwtrent

Comment: take a look at the second answer...You can view devices through their file handles and associations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KeyBoard, Mouse these devices are related to character drivers. You can go into "/proc" and see the devices and driver numbers there Or using "lsmod" command you can see the devices used by system. Or you may use this link "http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.4/html/x856.html" to know in details.